# What does it mean for two polynomials to be the same in this fundamental field extension theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields

I just read about the following "fundamental" theorem of field extensions which is stated as follows:

**Let $F$ be a field, and let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ be elements of field extensions $K/F$ and $L/F$. Suppose that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are algebraic over $F$. There is an isomorphism of fields $\sigma: F(\alpha) \rightarrow F(\beta)$ that is the identity on $F$ and that sends $\alpha \mapsto \beta$ if and only if the irreducible polynomials for $\alpha$ and $\beta$ over $F$ are equal.**

I was a little confused on what it means by what it means for two polynomials to be the same. My confusion stems from this example, where $F=\mathbb{F}_{3}$ and we consider $\mathbb{F}_{3}(\delta)$ where $\delta$ is the root of $x^{2}-2$. We have that $\eta= \delta +1$ is the root of $x^{2}+2x-1$. The field extensions $\mathbb{F}_{3}(\delta)$ and $\mathbb{F}_{3}(\eta)$ should be isomorphic by a map which sends $\delta$ to $\eta$. I don't quite see how these polynomials are the same. **Did I miss something?**

Comment: I think you meant to say that $\eta$ is a root of $x^2+x-1$...or I messed up my calculation.

Comment: Wow, nevermind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the part "the fields should be isomorphic" is not true. They are NOT isomporphic.

Assume that there is an isomorphism $F$ sending $\delta$ to $\eta$.

Then $$2=F(\delta^2)=F(\delta)^2=\eta^2$$

But this is not possible.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot, the example was insipired by another example from the book I am reading (Artin). The example he gave was $\alpha$ is a root of $x^{3}-x +1$ and $\beta=\alpha +1$ is a root of $x^{3}-3x^2+2x+1$. He then states that $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ are the same. In this case, is something different?

Comment: Does he say what the isomorphism is between $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$? Because if it doesn't send $\alpha$ to $\beta$ then the theorem doesn't apply.

Comment: No, he doesn't, he just says they are the same. So I guess the theorem does not apply. Thanks

Comment: It would be interesting to know what it is, and to check that the image of $\alpha$ does indeed have the same minimal polynomial as $\alpha$... This is an important observation - the theorem you are quoting gives necessary and sufficient conditions for a particular map $F(\alpha)\to F(\beta)$ to be an isomorphism, but the two fields may still be isomorphic even if this map is not an isomorphism.

Comment: @user135520 As Matt pointed the isomorphism DOESN'T send $\alpha$ to $\beta$. In that case you have $\beta=\alpha+1 \in \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ therefore $\mathbb Q(\beta) \subset \mathbb Q(\alpha)$ and $\alpha=\beta-1 \in \mathbb Q(\beta)$ therefore $\mathbb Q(\alpha) \subset \mathbb Q(\beta)$ .

Comment: Thanks, for all your help guys. I think, I should take a closer look from here.